# Android - Exoplayer : How to set different controller layout for portrait mode and fullscreen mode?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to achieve this design with Exo-Player2. Progressbar and some other views position is different in portrait mode and fullscreen mode.

[image: portrait mode]
[image: landcape mode]

As per my research we can pass only one layout design through player view by this line of code: `app:controller_layout_id="@layout/bplayer_controller_view"`

```
        <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
            android:id="@+id/playerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            app:controller_layout_id="@layout/bplayer_controller_view"
            app:resize_mode="fill" />
```

I can't find any way to change this layout in runtime. Did I miss anything? Can you please help me on this topic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the `app:controller_layout_id` programmatically. You can also see the same mentioned [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/4700). There is no such method at this moment which allows you to directly set a custom controller on playerView and for now you have to add your controller to playerview in xml from where it gets inflated.

Now coming to your problem of having a different custom controller for Landscape and Potrait orientation. There is no direct way of it. Here are some work around options:

- Have two different ExoPlayer in your XML for orientation and potrait and hide/show them accordingly as per orientation change.
- The other option will be to have a single `FrameLayout` in which you can then inflate two different types of ExoPlayer XML Layouts according to the orientation change.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below:

Res folder -> Right Click -> New -> Android Resource Directory.

Choose layout as Resource Type at the popup that will be displayed(second dropdown).

Then, at the left side choose orientation press >> and OK. A layout_port folder will be created.

Finally, create a layout with the same name as in the main folder(bplayer_controller_view).

Android chooses the correct file depending on requested orientation at runtime!